# How can we programmatically login and have access token from Facebook considering I have the credentials of the user?

Tags: facebook-opengraph

Suppose I have the  credentials for the user but I cant have him manually enter it. How can I programmatically login into facebook and get the accesstoken with the desired permissions?

It will be great if somebody could give a sample code.

Comment: You shall use openid to get access token that you will use in API. Do not use credentials.